# Why is Ruby giving an error "point is not on curve"?

Tags: ruby, ssh, openssl, capistrano

When I run capistrano to deploy I get the following error.

```
cap aborted!
OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Point::Error: point is not on curve
```

I am using the latest versions of Capistrano, Ruby and Openssl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of the issue was that the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` was corrupted. By deleting the file the problem was fixed.

Comment: Thanks so much. I love you

Comment: x2 love from 2020